# Efficient application of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

How can the following definite integral be computed with Mathematica?

> $$
> -\frac14\int_1^{\infty}\!\!\frac{\sqrt{-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2}}{x (x^2+z)}\theta\!\left(-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x \text{ with $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$}.
> $$

**Warning:** hard, easy to loose time...

**For the brave ones I provide some details.**
It is a simple matter to find the antiderivative (**1**). However, it is hard to substitute the limits automatically (compare **2** and **3** with **5**). Below, I outline the procedure that I've tried and that may eventually lead to the analytic result. However, it is too cumbersome.

---

### 1. The indefinite integral

The indefinite integral can be computed using the `Rubi`, [the Rule-based Integrator](https://rulebasedintegration.org):

```
Get["Rubi`"]

v=Int[-(1/(4 x (x^2+z))) Sqrt[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2] ,x]

(* 1/4 ArcTan[(2 x^2+z)/Sqrt[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2]]
   -((y^2+z) ArcTan[(2 x^2 z+2 z^2-(y^2+z)^2)/((y^2+z) Sqrt[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2])])/(8 z)
   -((y^2+z) ArcTan[(2 x^2 z+(y^2+z)^2)/((y^2+z) Sqrt[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2])])/(8 z) *)
```

MA can also compute this integral, however, the result is longer. The added benefit of `Ruby` is that *the antiderivative is continuous in the required interval*. This is very important because it allows to use [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

---

### 2. Determination of limits for $0\le x<\infty$

Let us assume for the moment that the lower integration limit is 0 not 1, and let $y>0$. This case is easier to handle.

```
Assuming[y∈Reals&&z∈Reals,Reduce[((-2 x^2+2 x y-y^2-z>0&&2 x^2+2 x y+y^2+z>0)||(-2 x^2+2 x y-y^2-z<0&&2 x^2+2 x y+y^2+z<0))&&0<x&&y>0,x]]

(* y>0 && ((z<=-y^2         && -(y/2)+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])||
           (-y^2<z<-(y^2/2) && y/2-1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])) *)
```

---

### 3. A by hand substitution

Using 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\arctan(x)=\pm\frac{\pi}2,
$$
a simple result can be obtained

```
f=Piecewise[{{π/4-(π (y^2+z))/(4 z),z<=-y^2},{π/4+(π (y^2+z))/(4 z),-y^2<z<-(y^2/2)}}]
```

It is desirable that MA can do these limits automatically. However, it seems not capable to determine that the expression under the square root is positive even given the needed assumptions. **A simpler question is** how to implement the limits with assumptions in MA?

---

### 4. Plot the result

```
 Block[{y=3},Plot[{f,NIntegrate[-(1/(4 x (x^2+z))) Sqrt[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2] HeavisideTheta[-4 x^4-4 x^2 z-(y^2+z)^2] ,{x,1,∞}]},{z,-30,0}]]
```

Analytical result *is* different from the numerical one, and *it is clear why*—the integral should be in the $1\le x<\infty$ limits.

[image]

---

### 5. Setting the limits right ($1\le x<\infty$) and the actual problem

```
Assuming[y∈Reals&&z∈Reals,Reduce[((-2 x^2+2 x y-y^2-z>0&&2 x^2+2 x y+y^2+z>0)||(-2 x^2+2 x y-y^2-z<0&&2 x^2+2 x y+y^2+z<0))&&1<x&&y>0,x]]

(* (0<y<1&&   ((z<=-2-2 y-y^2&&-(y/2)+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])||
                   (-2-2 y-y^2<z<-2+2 y-y^2&&1<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])))||
   (1<=y<=2&& ((z<-2-2 y-y^2&&-(y/2)+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])||
                   (-2-2 y-y^2<=z<-2+2 y-y^2&&1<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])))||
   (y>2&&     ((z<-2-2 y-y^2&&-(y/2)+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])||
                   (-2-2 y-y^2<=z<=-2+2 y-y^2&&1<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z])||
                   (-2+2 y-y^2<z<-(y^2/2)&&y/2-1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]<x<y/2+1/2 Sqrt[-y^2-2 z]))) *)
```

Now the route is clear: one just needs to go case by case and evaluate the antiderivative at the respective limits. **The antiderivative is continuous**, which greatly simplifies the problem. Yet, it is not for human hands. Therefore **the harder question**: how can these limits be computed analytically with MA given the antiderivative and the 7 cases above?